# Not able to display value with JSTL tag

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I having a simple code which works with servlet and JSP. Usually it works when i use the following code. 
However, that is some odds that i got this unexpected error and couldnt figure out whats the problem

```
Caused by:
javax.el.ELException - Cannot convert testID of type class java.lang.String to    
class java.lang.Integer
```

My Result class

```
public class Result {
    private String testID ; 
    private String date ; 
    private String result ;
    private String grade ;

    public String getTestID() {
        return testID;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setTestID(String testID) {
        this.testID = testID;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
```

}

my Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String testID = request.getParameter("Action").trim();
     User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("currentSessionUser");
     String sql = "select * from result where testID =" + testID + " and userID = " + user.getUserID();   
     PreparedStatement ps = DBconnection.getPreparedStatement(sql); 
     List <Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>(); 

     try {

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            Result result = new Result();

            result.setTestID(rs.getString("testID"));
            result.setGrade(rs.getString("grade"));
            result.setDate(rs.getString("dates"));
            result.setResult(rs.getString("result"));
            results.add(result);

        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     finally
     {
         DBconnection.close();
     }


     request.getSession().setAttribute("results", results);
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() +"/faces/subResult.jsp");
```

my JSP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
   <title>Insert title here</title>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
</head>
<body>


<ul>

<c:forEach items="${results}" var="results">
 <li> ${results.testID} </li>
 <li><c:out value="${result.grade}" /></li>
  <li><c:out value="${result.result}" /></li>
  <li>Hello</li>
 </c:forEach>

</ul>
</body>
```

Stack Trace

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert testID of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3748)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert testID of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:338)
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:309)
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:422)
at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.PropertyResolverToELResolver.coerceToInt(PropertyResolverToELResolver.java:271)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.convert.PropertyResolverToELResolver.getValue(PropertyResolverToELResolver.java:157)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:778)
at com.ibm._jsp._subResult._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(_subResult.java:182)
at com.ibm._jsp._subResult._jspService(_subResult.java:98)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
at com.FYP.servletGetSubResult.doGet(servletGetSubResult.java:74)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1229)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:367)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:94)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:66)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
... 25 more
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception. Also, the whole point of prepared statements is to be able to pass parameters safely, but you're using string concatenation to do that, leaving the code open to SQL injection attacks. And why are you storing the results to the session and redirecting to a view, rather than storing them in the request, and forwading to a view?

Comment: @JBNizet Hi, sorry for the inconvenience. I've added the stack trace. as for the Prepared statement, indeed i am aware of it, it is because i still running testing for this idea of code, hence i left it to simple way to test run first. I am still new to JSP , hence i thought that if i have a list of object, using session is much easier to achieve what i want to do

Comment: Not sure if that has something to do with the exception, but naming the current item `results`(in `var="results"`) is a bad idea: it's the same name as the collection itself. Name it `result`, and change `${results.testID}` to `${result.testID}`.

Comment: @JBNizet I was thinking the same thing. hiboss try and follow this suggestion and let us know if that solved the issue

Comment: @JBNizet  Yes It's Work. Thank you so much for bearing my silly mistake. A big thank you to you guys :) have a good day

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that isn't correct? That will confuse future readers. Delete your question, ask @AngeloOparah to fix his answer , or answer it yourself with the correct explanation. Don't just accept an answer if it's not correct, even if his author was helpful.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense: I'm happy to fix the answer and mention @JBNizet. hiboss feel free to delete your question, repost it and answer it yourself.

Comment: @AngeloOparah just edit your answer, since it's already accepted. No need to mention me.

Comment: @JBNizet just thought it's fair to give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this line is giving issues

```
<li> ${results.testID + ""} </li>
```

I'm wondering what is the purpose of that. Why are you trying to concatenate an Integer with an empty String?

Concatenation in `el` is not achieved with the `+` operator. You just have to place to el expressions close to each other.

The following should work

```
<li> ${results.testID} ${""}</li>
```

and this would do the same, but make more sense

```
<li> ${results.testID}</li>
```

Edit:

As JB Nizet as pointed out on his comment to the question the problem is caused by a bad choice when naming the variable that refers to the current item.

Quoting him:

> Not sure if that has something to do with the exception, but naming
>   the current item results(in var="results") is a bad idea: it's the
>   same name as the collection itself. Name it result, and change
>   ${results.testID} to ${result.testID}.

Comment: Same result.. because initially I've put  <li> ${results.testID}</li> , however, it show the same error. Hence I try put to empty string to enforce it to be string. Nevertheless, its my mistake to put that. will edit it

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you defined Result.testID to be Integer (in Result class).
But in your database the testID column is String. Most data are numeric, so `result.setTestID(rs.getString("testID"));` does not usually fail, but you have some cases where database data in testID column is not numeric.  Thus the "Cannot convert testID of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Integer" error

Comment: Strangly that both are String. I am able to System.out.println(result.getTestID) in servlet. however, when i brought it to JSP, heres the error occured